# Pegar string entre barras

Tags: javascript

Galera preciso pegar a string que esta dentro das duas ultimas barras (heDA6Yu7hsc) com javascript. Como proceder?

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/heDA6Yu7hsc/img.jpg
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tente desta forma abaixo:

```js
var url="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/heDA6Yu7hsc/img.jpg";
var part = url.split("/");
console.log(part[4]);
```

Cada parte do *array* gerado corresponde a uma quebra do `split`

```
[0]=https:
[1]=
[2]=i.ytimg.com
[3]=vi
[4]=heDA6Yu7hsc
[5]=img.jpg
```

Comment: Cara, perfeito. Obrigado!!!!

Comment: ^^, quem bom q ajudei

Comment: não esquece d marcar como resolvido

Answer (score 2):

Você também pode fazer por expressão regular.

```js
var texto = /\/([\w\d]+)\/[\w.]+$/gi.exec("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/heDA6Yu7hsc/img.jpg");
console.log(texto[1]);
```